# Editing multiple selection based on user choice

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to solve this for awhile, and I'd appreciate it if someone can help me. Here is my problem.

[image]

Here is my code; it's simply view the content of a Job Table in the Database and perform a edition as needed, based on the selection. The checkbox is next to each job, and there is an update button at the end of the page to submit..

I'm getting an error updating it.  Please help me.

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
     include('../CIEcon.php');

    echo "<form action= 'adminCleaning.php'  method = 'post'>" ; 
// when the user click update..         
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            if( empty($_POST['Id'])   || $_POST['Id'] == 0 ){
     echo"<h4>  please choose something to update   </h4>";
         echo"test(1): pass <br> ";
              }else{

            // comes here even though u dind't chhose, cause
            // it set IDs next to each feild.. 
             echo"!!....HERE....!! ";   
                }
            }// end of update $_POAT[update]

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cleaning ";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

                          /// NOW DISPLAY ALL INFO FROM CHOSEN DATABASE...

                                echo "

    <table cellpadding ='4' border='1' width='80%' align='center'>
 <tr>

    <th class='tt' >Check </th>
    <th class='tt'> Job's Name</th>
    <th class='tt' >Description</th>
    <th class='tt' > No Students needed</th>
    <th class='tt' >Due Date</th>
    </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='".$row['Id']."' /> </td>";  // array[] cause to edit more than one record... 
            echo "<td>".'<input type="text"  name="jobname['.$row['Id'].']"     value='.$row['JobName'].' >'."</td>";
            echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="description['.$row['Id'].']"   value='.$row['Description'].'> '."</td>";
            echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="nostudent['.$row['Id'].']"     value='.$row['NoStudent'].'>'."</td>";
            echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="duedate['.$row['Id'].']"        value='.$row['DueDate'].'>'."</td>";

  echo "<input type=hidden name='Id[]'  value='".$row['Id']."' >";

            echo "</tr>";
    echo "jobname['.$row[Id].']" ;  // testing. 
    echo "description['.$row[Id].']" ;  // testing. 
    echo "nostudent['.$row[Id].']" ;  // testing. 
                                }
                                echo "</table>";
                       /// END THE SEARCH HERE...........

                                echo " <br>
                                    <div align='center'>
                                    <input type='reset' value='clear' /> 

                                    <input type='submit' name='update' value='update' />

                                    </div> ";

                              mysqli_close($dbCIE);

    echo "</form>";
    }
    else{echo "must logout to see this page..!!";}

    ?>

    <html>

    <head><title> ..Cleanding.... </title></head>

    <style type="text/css">

    body{
        margin-top: 70px;    /*space above the table....*/
        background-color: #23438e; 
    }
    table{
        background-color: white; 
    }


    .tt{
        background: #f26822;
        color: white ;
    }
    </style>


    <body>

    <!-- <a href= "../AdminIndex.php" > <button> Main Page </button></a>     -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Major issue: you're `echo`ing everything outside(above) `<html>` tag.

Comment: it's ok, to echo everything above, it's working fine with addition and delete

Comment: First of all, that's not a *valid* html code. You need to display everything inside `<body> /* display here */ </body>`. And second, you'll get an array of job ids after submitting the form. Then, what would you like to do with it inside `if(isset($_POST['update'])){ ... }`?

Comment: You said *I'm getting error updating it*. What's this error you're getting?

Comment: insdie the form, is where the user checktbox any recrod, and finish updating, and click the button ''update'' will triger the 
if(isset($_POST['update'])){ ... }

Comment: You still didn't give me any concrete answer. What do you want to do with *those* array of job ids, which you're getting with `$_POST['Id']`, in `if(isset($_POST['update'])){ ... }`?

Comment: Thank u sir for ur answer.. when I tried to user $_post[jobname][id] to make changes, it tells me that jobname is undefined..  and I deleted the whole update querey, and i want to build a correct one.

Comment: that's why I deleted it from my code.. I want to find some better way to  update the record

Comment: $impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['Id']);
          
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Cleaning SET 
 JobName='".$_POST['jobname']."',
 Description='".$_POST['description']."',
 NoStudent='".$_POST['nostudent']."',
 DueDate='".$_POST['duedate']."'
 WHERE Id IN('" . $impid  . "')";
$resultUpdate = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlUpdate ) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

Comment: this method would work only on the last record, but not any other recrod..

Comment: I've given an answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Grammar really needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your form and table are outside of `<body>` tag. You have to display everything like this: `<body> **display here** </body>`

Second, remove this line `echo "<input type=hidden name='Id[]'  value='".$row['Id']."' >";` from your code, it's not required.

And now comes to your question, `$_POST['Id']` is an array of job ids, so use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to check if the array is empty or not and use `foreach` loop to update each individual row. So you should process your form like this:

```
// when the user click update..         
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    if(count($_POST['Id'])){

        // $_POST['Id'] is an array of job id
        foreach($_POST['Id'] as $v){
            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Cleaning SET JobName='" . $_POST['jobname'][$v] . "', Description='" . $_POST['description'][$v] . "', NoStudent='" . $_POST['nostudent'][$v] ."', DueDate='" . $_POST['duedate'][$v] . "' WHERE Id = '" . $v . "'";
            $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlUpdate) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

            // If you want you can use mysqli_affected_rows() function to 
            // check how many were affected by the UPDATE query
        }


    }else{

        echo"<h4>please choose something to update</h4>";

    }

}
```

And your entire code should be like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title> ..Cleanding.... </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin-top: 70px;    /*space above the table....*/
            background-color: #23438e; 
        }
        table{
            background-color: white; 
        }
        .tt{
            background: #f26822;
            color: white ;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
        include('../CIEcon.php');

        // when the user click update..         
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){

            if(count($_POST['Id'])){

                // $_POST['Id'] is an array of job id
                foreach($_POST['Id'] as $v){
                    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Cleaning SET JobName='" . $_POST['jobname'][$v] . "', Description='" . $_POST['description'][$v] . "', NoStudent='" . $_POST['nostudent'][$v] ."', DueDate='" . $_POST['duedate'][$v] . "' WHERE Id = '" . $v . "'";
                    $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlUpdate) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

                    // If you want you can mysqli_affected_rows() function to 
                    // check how many were affected by the UPDATE query
                }


            }else{

                echo"<h4>please choose something to update</h4>";

            }

        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cleaning ";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));
        ?>
        <form action= 'adminCleaning.php' method = 'post'>
            <table cellpadding ='4' border='1' width='80%' align='center'>
            <tr>

            <th class='tt' >Check </th>
            <th class='tt'> Job's Name</th>
            <th class='tt' >Description</th>
            <th class='tt' > No Students needed</th>
            <th class='tt' >Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" name="Id[]" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" /> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="jobname[<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['JobName']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description[<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Description']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nostudent[<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['NoStudent']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="duedate[<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['DueDate']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
            <input type="reset" value="clear" />
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" />
        </form>

        <br />
        <div align='center'>
        </div>
        <?php
            mysqli_close($dbCIE);
    }
    else{
        echo "must logout to see this page..!!";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Man , u're one of the BEST programmer I've ever Seen in my life.. WOW
VERY IMPRESSED...
U got it man, THANK U SO MUCH